# inflate exception widget recycleview

Tags: java, android, xml

On the line below an error is thrown

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.widget.RecycleView

What am I missing?

**Code**

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.xxx.yyyy;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
//import android.support.v7.app.AlertController;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
DBHandler dbHandler = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.app.widget.RecycleView
    android:id="@+id/esp_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.app.widget.RecycleView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in xml. RecycleView instead of RecyclerView (r letter at the end of Recycler is missing)